# Square Blocks with Flex Box

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

Is there a way to get all boxes to be equal to the height (and width) of the largest box using `display: flex;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;`. It appears to only work on folks in the same line.
This pen illustrates the problem some more: http://codepen.io/komplexb/pen/gbqgXq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are already setting a height on the parent element (and that the parent element is square), you would just need to give the children flexbox items a height of `50%`.

In doing so, the `flex-basis` (shorthand) value of `50%` combined with a height of `50%` will result in perfectly square flexbox items since the parent is square.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvGmeO)

```
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This does work to an extent. But that now gives the `li` a fixed height. So it won't grow/shrink based on content. The main aim here is to be able to get every `li` in a given `ul` to take the height of the tallest li among them. As i mentioned this seems to only occur for boxes in the same row.

Comment: @komplexb But if all the `li` elements take the height of the tallest `li`, then the `li` elements won't be square if there are multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, thats correct. Also someone chimed in on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JoniTrythall/status/581102450943328258), it appears your solution is the closest I can get without adding JS. Thanks.